# What is the category/group for the typographical terms serif and sans-serif

Tags: terminology, hypernyms, typography

I teach introductory typography to students studying graphic design.

While constructing a list of design factors that affect the appearance, readability, and legibility of a typographic letterform, symbol, glyph, etc.; I hit a wall.

I am looking for the collective term category/group name for the styles whose letterforms can be differentiated by the presence or absence of a design **trait** — serif, sans serif.

The definitions of each are well documented:

In typography, serifs are semi-structural details on the ends of some of the strokes that make up letters and symbols. A typeface that has serifs is called a serif typeface (or seriffed typeface). A typeface without serifs is called sans-serif, from the French sans, meaning “without”. Some typography sources refer to sans-serif typefaces as “grotesque” (in German “grotesk”) or “Gothic”, and serif types as “Roman”.

Here's the list I prepared to meet my deadline. I had to go with **stroke**. Can I do any better for my revision?

Here are factors that affect ease of reading.

- case: upper & lower case mix is more readable than all caps
- x-height: larger is more readable than smaller
- leading: more is more readable than solid
- line length: shorter (10-12 words) are more easily readable than longer
- alignment: ragged-right is more readable than justified
- weight: medium is more readable than light or bold
- measure: normal is more readable than condensed or expanded
- margins: moderate is more readable than tight
- contrast: black (dark) on yellow (light) background is more readable than others
- substrate: smooth backgrounds are more readable than textured ones
- stroke: many agree that serifs are more readable than sans serifs

Comment: I'd say things like [*ball terminals,  beaks, ears, finials, swashes, tails, tapers, serifs,* etc.](https://www.fontsmith.com/blog/2016/06/29/the-a-z-of-typographic-terms) are "optional embellishments".

Comment: Orthographic features?

Comment: They are geographical terms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Serriffe

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's interesting given that serifs (adornment) pre-date plain-ended letter strokes. "Fancy" pre-dated "plain." What word(s) describe the "treatment/group" to which all of those refer? These all refer to serifs.

Comment: @HotLicks Bless you for that. You made my day!

Comment: The stroke is usually the main factor in font **classification**, so _class_ might work?

Answer (score 1):

[***Anatomy:***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anatomy)

> A study of the structure or internal workings of something.

(Oxford Dictionary)

This would seem to be the most appropriate word to use.

**Stroke** is used for a particular typographic detail, specifically the main vertical diagonal of a letter, so should not be used as the generic term for the letter elements.

Anatomy is used by a number of resources to describe the elements of letterforms.

[Typedia](http://typedia.com/learn/only/anatomy-of-a-typeface/) - Anatomy of a Typeface

[Fonts.com](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-1/type-anatomy/anatomy) - Anatomy of a Character

[Visme](http://blog.visme.co/type-anatomy/) - A Visual Guide to the Anatomy of Typography

Comment: I was/am looking for a specific (not generic) term inclusive of both. You misunderstood my requirement. Strokes have a beginning and an end. As such, I require a term inclusive to the ends formed with any of a variety or none at all.

Answer (score 1):

In typography, any stem or stroke which does not end in a serif is called a **terminal**. There are a number of terminal varieties, just as there are different varieties of serifs. The differentiating term for the two possible outcomes is **stem/stroke ending.**

See: [Typography Deconstructed](https://typedecon.com/blogs/type-glossary/stroke/)